# How to restrict certain files on my website from being viewed using XML (or alternative)

Tags: javascript, xml, passwords

On my website, I would like to upload the .png files for my webcomic in advance, but I don't want them to be viewable by spiders (google images) and people who manage to guess the URLs. Is there a way I can restrict specific files from being viewed via some sort of reference file, like an XML, so I can add and remove the restriction when I need to?

Preferably this XML could be manipulated via a PHP script or JavaScript that has a password.

Example: "/uploads/file_id/image_name.png" would return nothing, even though it does exist. The XML would have a field that says "/uploads/file_id"'s contents are restricted and cannot be read.

EDIT: I am using Dreamhost, I have Apache, PHP 7.1, and HTTPS SLS encryption on my connections enforced by .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

If a user can view your file, they can save your file. No amount of server or client side configuration can prevent that, but there are ways to mitigate some of your undesired behaviors. But remember, **the best way to combat piracy is to make getting things easier than it would be pirating them.**

### Use a session/user token system

Client and server configurations vary widely and you haven't gone into detail (e.g. is this web server served over HTTP or over HTTPS? What server technologies are you using?) but I'm sure you can find a way to supply a limited time use or one time use token to your client when you first access the web page. Requests to resources can be sent with this token and you can send along with it an `HTTP 200: Success` when the token matches the server's list of valid tokens. You could even make sure that when the tokens are used they match the IP addresses of the clients they were issued to.

When the token is expired/invalid, you send an `HTTP 403: Access denied`, ensuring that even if a crawler gets resources, that link will not resolve again.

These tokens should not be guessable and shouldn't be reused. Crawlers that don't support JavaScript have already failed to crawl your true resources. If this is over HTTP, hypothetically the token could be stolen, but again, if these resources are already accessible through simpler means, there's no reason for someone doing this.

Though, crawlers are quite advanced nowadays, so if you really want to secure your tokens and make sure they aren't being generated by bots, put your token delivery behind a human verification system like CAPTCHA or have a user registration system for your site.

Comment: I am using Dreamhost, I have Apache, PHP 7.1, and HTTPS SLS encryption on my connections enforced by .htaccess. I'm not to concerned with piracy, as there is nothing I can do about that. I just don't want certain files to be viewable until I release them. Like a private YOUTUBE video.